# Const Array working in php 5.6?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, constants

In the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), it is stated in user contributed notes that const array is now allowed. I even checked other posts here in stackoverflow and they said the same. I tested the following code:

```
<?php

class Constants{
      const test = array("a"=>"apple","b"=>"ball","c"=>"car");
}
echo Constants::test["b"];
echo Constants::test["c"];
echo Constants::test["a"];
?>
```

Output:

```
ball
car
apple
```

The above code works. However This doesn't work if I use `define('test',array("a"=>"apple","b"=>"ball","c"=>"car")` outside of the class. Is this a new undocumented change or happening only in my setup?

My setup is php 5.6.1(32-bit thread safe) and apache 2.4.10 (32-bit) on windows 7 x64. I downloaded them from the their respective sites directly. I didn't use any WAMP stacks.

Also note that I am using netbeans 8.0.1 IDE for hints and it shows this error. Anyone know how to remove it?

```
Syntax error
unexpected: [
after:  identifier 'test'
expected:   instanceof, as, =>, }, ',', OR, XOR, &&, ?, ;, ||, &&, |, ^, &, ==, !=, ===, !==, <=,
>=, <, >, <<, >>, +, -, *, /, %, '.', ], (, ), :
----
```

Comment: From http://php.net/const: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values, or scalar or array values in PHP 5.6 and later.

Comment: @RocketHazmat but he has 5.6

Comment: @Cheery: I think I mis-read the question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You read the question correctly. I didn't read the page from manual you posted which states that array constants was indeed added in PHP 5.6. Anyway do you know how to remove the error from netbeans?

Comment: You probably already checked this, but is the PHP Version in your project properties set to 5.6?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes the php version in project properties in netbeans is set to 5.6

Comment: Is your define working when executed in a normal PHP context? Is it only breaking within your IDE?

Comment: @ToBe The define doesn't work when executed as PHP. But it doesn't matter because now you can use const outside of a class. BTW thank you. I resolved the error in the IDE without using a class.

Comment: i wondered about a similar error being displayed using Jetbrains PHPstorm (latest version 8.0.1) with PHP version 5.6 enabled in settings - with the same scenario. The strange thing here is if I define an empty array to a constant the IDE says its fine when I put any value inside the array it reports a syntax error. Maybe its a common bug across IDE's?

Comment: @Steini Are you using define() or const to define the empty array to a constant? It looks like PHP stopped improving on define() after introducing const outside of classes in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @up ofcourse im using const keyword, define is ugly as its a function call, PHPStorm tells me "expression is not allowed in a class constant value."  and outsode of a class it reports "expression is not alled in a constnat value."  But if I execute the code it works perfectly fine without an error so PHPstorm does not support it yet or its a bug.

Comment: @Steini It looks like they didn't add it in PHPstorm. There is no error in netbeans at the defining of the const both inside and outside of the class. The error I am having is when calling Constants::test["b"]. My bad for not mentioning the location of the error in my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if I use const outside of a class, the error in netbeans IDE won't show up.

```
const test = array("a"=>"apple","b"=>"ball","c"=>"car");
echo test["b"];
echo test["c"];
echo test["a"];
```

This should work!